# Is it efficient to use MongoDB partial index feature?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design, schema

I'm going to create signup, sign in functionality.
user can register with email, or Mobile number and since I need index on both of these fields I'm thinking what will be the best practice to achieve good performance and correct way of doing it.

user might register with either mobile or email, and at the time of registration one of these fields will be empty, and fields must be unique.
what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Even if one of the field will be empty, you can go ahead and create indexes on both of these keys separately using [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) index. However sparse index on a collection cannot return complete results, you will have to careful with its usage.

Another approach you can it create a field like and "primary_login_key" which can either be an email or a mobile number. This allows you to have a single non sparse index. However this wont scale as in future if the user want to connect multiple methods to his profile, you will anyway have to create those keys and indexes on them.

Comment: Thank you @Arbaz , I don't want to use sparse index because of MongoDB recommendation it's better to use partialIndex instead of Sparse index, But my Question is, Is this efficient at all to use any of them?

Answer (score 0):

A user collection will have a structure like this, in general:

*user:*

```
_id
fullname
username
email
phone
etc.
```

Keeping the *registration details* separately from the *user details* will help managing the data based on its functionality. So, introduce a field which is specific to registration. A user's document can have the `registration` field with the following shape:

```
registration: { email: "myname@mymail.com" }
-or-
registration: { phone: "999-888-1234" }
```

This will allow the registration phone or the email to be unique. You can create unique index the two fields separately. For this use the [partial indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/). For example:

```
db.user.createIndex(
   { "registration.email": 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "registration.email": { $exists: true } } }
)

db.user.createIndex(
   { "registration.phone": 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "registration.phone": { $exists: true } } }
)
```

This can also mean duplication of some of the data like phone or email. The application will need to handle it based on the functionality.

The options to think about:

- Use the available registered phone or email (and the registered email
  or phone cannot be changed).
- Have the user phone and email fields separately from the registered
  phone or email (the question to ask is: "What if the user wants to
  change the user email or user phone?").

Comment: Thank you @parsad_, I'm thinking about this solution that you provide, But is this fine at all to use Partial Index? I read a lot that this might bring some performance issue is large amount of data. any experiences about that?

Comment: _"I read a lot that this might bring some performance issue is large amount of data..."_ Where did you know about this? Do you have a source or link?

Comment: In general, indexes are used for fast searches and sorts. If you are looking for performance with your queries, indexes are the way to go. When used correctly indexes always give the desired results. There are different kinds of indexes based upon the usage criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As you have provide the details, there could be three cases of data:

1. collection has phone number, but no email
2. collection has email but no phone number
3. collection can has both the fields phone number as email.

Assuming, user can create two accounts, one using phone number and other using email.

And, It will be totally upto user have he provide email after creating account using phone number, or provide phone number after creating account using email.

So, I things its better to go ahead with creating Compound Index using two fields i.e "phoneNumber" and "email".
As, this will cover all three cases of collections.

```
    db.collection.createIndex( { phone:1, email: 1 } )
```

Above will create index, using both the fields.